# CTRL opens default browser

Tags: windows, browser, keyboard, default, ctrl

My left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button opens new window of my default web browser. First it was Chrome, but when I uninstalled that it did the same with Explorer. I found only 2 topics like this on Google but not the working solution.

Strange is that this startet to happen today, never in the past and I did not do anything with binds/shortcuts at all.

Tried to reinstall Chrome even with personal setting, but as it did the same with Explorer I think it's Windows or Keyboard problem. Can you help me please?

EDIT: Also the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button changes the songs when playing via Media Player.
The notebook keyboard is all right, only external USB keyboard do this.

Comment: New update/ Fix: Just turn off the Human Interface Devices service an youre good to go. [link to how to turn the service on/off](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-security/windows-auto-open-a-browser-when-i-press-ctrl/9c5df376-50f1-4fa2-84fe-41cf0505be6a?auth=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely the USB keyboard. Fixing stuffs like this, you must first start troubleshooting with the physical devices. It could be that the other keys are malfunctioning such that it looks you're doing shortcut commands. I had an experience with this once. Other keys are just stuck and they kinda seem always pressed.

Comment: I just tried something with device manager. This keyboard, when plugged, was displayed as 3 devices. One of them had the "disable" option, so I uninstalled this one and seems like it solved my problem.

Anyway, thanks.